# How to have string between ":" calculate column?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, custom-list, calculated-column

I'm working on SharePoint Enterprise 2013.
I have a column call **"CountryWF"** wich shows **Country:state:city**. I need a calculate column to shows between ":" which is **State**. I made some columns and each returned different but not State.

For example the column is:  **United States:Virginia:Falls church**
I use the code bellow:

```
 (MID([CountryWF], FIND(":", [CountryWF])+1, LEN([CountryWF]))
```

and  the out put will be: **Virginia:Falls church**  but I need only **Virginia**. I also tried this code:

```
 =MID([CountryWF], SEARCH(":",[CountryWF],0)), SEARCH(":", [CountryWF], 0))​
```

but it contain syntax error and didn't work. If any one could help me I appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this - Assuming data is in the correct format in all cases

```
=LEFT((MID(CountryWF,FIND(":",CountryWF)+1,LEN(CountryWF))), FIND(":",(MID(CountryWF,FIND(":",CountryWF)+1,LEN(CountryWF))))-1)
```